# How to compile hbs and json with static assets (css, images) to use with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to generate a pdf using puppeteer and hbs as template. When I try to compile the hbs and the json with the data, the images and the css are not compiled together and doesn't show in the pdf.

It will only work when I call the res.render passing the template and the json.

How can I fix the code to compile the template and the json together with the static css?

I already set the static path 'public' with the express and because of that it works when I call the api method that return res.render(template, data).

```
const express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const app = express();
const data = require('./database.json');

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const compile = async function(templateName, data) {
  const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'views', `${templateName}.hbs`);
  const html = await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8');
  return hbs.compile(html)(data);
};

app.get('/export/pdf', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const content = await compile('invoice', data);
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent(content);
    const buffer = await page.pdf({
      path: 'mypdf.pdf',
      format: 'A4',
      margin: { top: "20px", left: "20px", right: "20px", bottom: "20px" },
      printBackground: true
    });
    res.type('application/pdf');
    res.send(buffer)
    await browser.close()
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error', e);
  }
});
```

I want the pdf to be generated with the external css and images. At the moment everytime I call the api /export/pdf (as shown in the code) it will generate the pdf without the css and images.